# How can i encrypt a web.config variable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, security, web-config

I have to put a password in my web.config and i need to encrypt it and use in my code, is there some tip to how to do this?

Code of my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Password" value="test123"/>
</appSettings>
```

How im getting it:

```
string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article on [Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

Comment: ScottGu has collected a few links about this topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My tip for u: Search for ProtectedConfigurationProvider on google.

I have implemented a custom ProtectedConfigurationProvider before in our application. Searching for it on google gave me a few hits, for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfc2t3az.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use [FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile.aspx) and store encrypt password in config file..

```
void HashPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
               string hashMethod = "";

               if (md5.Checked)
               {
                  hashMethod = "MD5";
               }
               else
               {
                  hashMethod = "SHA1";
               }

               string hashedPassword =
                  FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password.Text, hashMethod);

               result.Text = "&lt;credentials passwordFormat=\"" + hashMethod +"\"&gt;<br />" +
                  "  &lt;user name=\"" + Server.HtmlEncode(userName.Text) + "\" password=\"" +
                  hashedPassword + "\" /&gt;<br />" + "&lt;/credentials&gt;";
            }
            else
            {
               result.Text = "There was an error on the page.";
            }
         }
```

> As you said you want to encrypt the config section check this-
>   [Encrypt sections of Web.Config or App.Config](http://dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx) and MSDN - [How to
>   encrypt sensitive data in Machine.config and Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx#pagpractices0001_conhowtoencryptsensitivedatainmachineconfigandwebconfig) in the *Security Practices: ASP.NET Security Practices at a Glance* section.

Example:

```
copy App.Config App.Config.original
rename App.config web.config
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings . -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
rename web.config App.config
```